# Combinatorics: St. Peter's Game algorithm

Tags: haskell, combinatorics, fold, circular-list, run-length-encoding

There's a combinatorics puzzle (as mentioned in *Mathematics From the Birth of Numbers* by Jan Gullberg) where if you line up fifteen members from two categories each (e.g. fifteen of category `0` and fifteen of category `1` for a total of `30` elements) mixed up in a *certain order*, then if you continuously go along this line *in a circular fashion* (i.e. wrapping around back to the start when you reach the end, continuing counting as you go) throwing out every *ninth* element, you'll eventually have just the elements of the one "favored" (`1`) category

```
line = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,...]
```

`line` (see the run-length encoded tuples version below) is the actual ordering, that if you throw out every ninth,

```
line = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,...] -- 9th thrown out
```

you'll always be throwing out the "disfavored" `0`. If seen from the RLE tuples standpoint (where `(0|1, n)` encodes `n` consecutive occurrences of the `0` or the `1`), (decrementing) from the tuple `(0,x)`, i.e., decrementing the `x`, you'll eventually get down to just the `(1,y)` tuples, of course throwing out the fully depleted `(0,0)` tuples as well and recompacting the list as you go

```
line = [(1,4),(0,5),(1,2),(0,1),(1,3),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,3),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1)]
```

I've got this to get started

```
tally = foldl (\acc elem -> if (snd(elem)+acc) >= 9
                            then (snd(elem)+acc)-9
                            else (snd(elem)+acc)) 0
```

and when I feed it `line`

```
tally [(1,4),(0,5),(1,2),(0,1),(1,3),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,3),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1)]
```

it takes the `4` of the first tuple, then adds the `5` of the second, gets `9` and resets the accumulator to start the "counting down the line" again. And so it accurately returns `3` which is, in fact, the leftover of the accumulator after going along for one pass and identifying the tuple with the ninth and resetting the accumulator. My obvious problem is how to go beyond just *identifying* the ninth elements, and actually start decrementing the `0` tuples' elements, as well as throwing them out when they're down to `(0,0)` and re-running. I'm sure it would be easier to just build `line` as

```
line = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,...]
```

and start chucking (i.. removing) the ninth, again, which should always be a `0` element, (e.g., the first ninth has been eliminated from `line`

```
line = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,...]
```

but this is more of a challenge because I essentially need a fold to be combined with a map -- which is what I want to learn, i.e., a purely functional, no counters, etc., style. Hints and help appreciated. Also, if someone in the combinatorics lore could shed some theory light on what's happening here, that would be nice, too.

Comment: It took me a long time to puzzle over the first paragraph and code snippet to parse it. It should be mentioned that a tuple `(i,n)` encodes a line of `n` items labeled `i`, i.e., `line` is a run-length encoding of a sequence of `1` and `0`, which is where you're removing "every ninth element" from. It would be better to first explain the setting with the naive encoding. A link to a description of this game would be extra nice because '"St Peter's game" combinatorics' currently has exactly one tangentially relevant Google result.

Comment: Okay, made some updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for maps and folds might be overconstraining things, because here's a cute no-frills function for you to start with:

```
-- Remove the n-th element (zero-indexed) of a run-length encoded sequence of a.
chuck :: Int -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
```

Throw out the empty case; we're not supposed to be here.

```
chuck _ [] = error "unexpected empty list"
```

Let's compute `chuck n ((a,m) : l)`. We're facing `m` identical elements `a`, and we want to delete the `n`-th element. That depends on whether `n < m` (i.e., whether the search stops in the middle of those `m` elements, or after).

If `n < m`, then we will remove one of those `a`. We can also prepare the result in anticipation for the next cycle, which resumes right after that `a` we removed. We've actually skipped `n` other elements before it, and a good place to store these `n` elements is the end of the list, since we're supposed to circle back around at the end anyway. We would need something more sophisticated if we wanted to count laps, but unless told otherwise, YAGNI. There remain `m-n-1` elements, left at the front. A little helper `rpt` helps in the case where we are trying to append zero elements.

`otherwise`, we skip all `m` elements, store them in the back, and we have `n-m` more to go.

```
chuck n ((a,m) : l)
  | n < m = rpt a (m-n-1) ++ l ++ rpt a n
  | otherwise = chuck (n-m) (l ++ [(a,m)])
  where rpt a 0 = []
        rpt a n = [(a,n)]
```

(Note: this splits up `(a,m)` into `(a,m-n-1)` and `(a,n)`, but doesn't merge them back... Left as an exercise for the reader.)

Since the result is prepared for the next iteration, we can easily chain `chuck` to see the evolution of the line. Note that elements are zero-indexed in this implementation, so `chuck 8` chucks the "ninth" element.

```
ghci
> line
[(1,4),(0,5),(1,2),(0,1),(1,3),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,3),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1)]
> chuck 8 line
[(1,2),(0,1),(1,3),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,3),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1),(1,4),(0,4)]
> chuck 8 $ chuck 8 line
[(0,1),(1,2),(0,3),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1),(1,4),(0,4),(1,2),(0,1),(1,3),(0,1),(1,1)]
```

This is a bit hard to follow. At the very least, we should make sure that only `0`'s are being chucked. So let's count the elements:

```
tally :: [(Int,Int)] -> (Int, Int)
tally xs = (sum (map snd (filter ((== 0) . fst) xs)), sum (map snd (filter ((== 1) . fst) xs)))
```

The right side of the tally seems to remain constant, and there is less on the wrong side, as expected:

```
> tally line
(15,15)
> tally $ chuck 8 line
(14,15)
> tally $ chuck 8 $ chuck 8 line
(13,15)
```

We can go faster with `iterate`, which repeatedly applies a function and returns all intermediate results in an infinite list:

```
> :t iterate
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

Iterate `chuck 8`, tally up, only look until where we expect to stop (after removing all 15 elements on one side):

```
> take 16 $ map tally $ iterate (chuck 8) line
[(15,15),(14,15),(13,15),(12,15),(11,15),(10,15),(9,15),(8,15),(7,15),(6,15),(5,15),(4,15),(3,15),(2,15),(1,15),(0,15)]
```

Comment: If I do `chuck 8` multiple times: `take 16 $ iterate (chuck 8) line` , the whole thing diverges, creating more and more tuple elements to the list, instead of just decrementing the `(0,x)` elements and leaving the `(1,y)` elements alone. What I'm needing is at the termination, just the list returned made up of the `(1,y)` elements, i.e., this is a crazy, round-about way of filtering the `(0,x)` elements out of the list . . . or I'm missing something you're doing here.

Comment: @147pm you are supposed to `take 1 . drop 15 . iterate (chuck 8) $ line` to see just the final line, without all the interim versions of it.

Comment: As I understand the problem, the final output should be `[(1,4),(1,2),(1,3),(1,1),(1,2),(1,1),(1,2)]`, not  `[[(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(1,3),(1,1),(1,2)]]`. And the second tuple elements are supposed to total to 15. Will look into it further if I'm seeing something wrong here..

Comment: It's a rotated version of the same list. This witnesses the fact that the walk stops in the middle of the initial list, rather than back at the beginning. Consider keeping track of where the initial list starts and ends an extra exercise.

Comment: Yes... Sorry...

Answer (score 2):

Using RLE complicates things. All you need is counting:

```
line = [(1,4),(0,5),(1,2),(0,1),(1,3),(0,1),(1,1),
        (0,2),(1,2),(0,3),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1)]
unRLE rle = [c | (c,n) <- rle, c <- replicate n c]
test = count9 1 (sum [n | (0,n) <- line]) -- 15 
                [] $ unRLE line

count9 _ 0 rev line   = reverse rev ++ line
count9 9 n rev (0:xs) = count9 1 (n-1) rev xs
 -- removing 1 is error:
count9 9 n rev (1:xs) = error "attempt to remove 1"
count9 i n rev (x:xs) = count9 (i+1) n (x:rev) xs
count9 i n rev []     = count9 i n [] (reverse rev)
```

Running it

```
> test
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

You will need to tweak this if you want to see the state of the `line` on each `0` being removed.

Comment: This is great recursion lore. Though I'm curious why you chose 15 in the `count9 1 15 [] line`.

Comment: because you have 15 zeroes to remove.